# Is there a way to save what the user has inputted via "Console.ReadLine()" in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program on Microsoft Visual Studio where it would create a list of things that the user input and put them in order from 1 to x (x being how every many things you input). It's a little bit hard to explain but this is roughly how it works: you would input a number (for example "7") and it would ask you to type 7 different things into the console. Once you're finished, it would randomly pick two different things that you entered and it would ask you which one you liked more. Eventually, using a bracket like system it would narrow it down to a winner and would make a list from the best to worst.

This is my code for when you enter x number of things for the list:

```
int numberOfThings = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
int times = 0;
do
{
    Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    times = times + 1;
}
while (numberOfThings != times);
```

The code works well but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to save the inputs from "Console.ReadLine()" to strings. There could be an easy answer for this but I'm fairly new to C# and I guess coding in general. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [Learn to manage data collections using List<T> in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections) ([browser version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/list-collection))

Comment: Are you aware of arrays, lists, or collections?

Comment: Also, note that you don't have to use `Convert.ToString` for the  `Console.ReadLine()` , because it returns a `string` so you could effectively do `string currentLine = Console.ReadLine();`. You can make `string` variables just like `int` or any other object type.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of an array to store the user inputs. I'll let you figure out randomly picking the inputs from there, but here's the code to store into an array:

```
int numberOfThings = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
// Add the array here
string[] inputs = new string[numberOfThings];
int times = 0;
do
{
    // Access an element of the array at position `times`, and store the value from the user there
    inputs[times] = Console.ReadLine();
    times = times + 1;
}
while (numberOfThings != times);

// Just putting this here to show you more examples of how to use an array (you can also use foreach as well)
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(inputs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to read a collection. First of all, you can try to read the
entire collecttion in one go while using a *delimiter* to separate items:

```
public static string[] ReadThings() {
  Console.WriteLine("PLease, enter things' names separating them by space");

  return Console
    .ReadLine()
    .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Another possibility is to read items until stop:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadThingsNames() {
  Console.WriteLine("PLease, enter things' names press enter to quit");

  for (int index = 1; ; ++index) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Please, enter thing #{index}");

    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
      break;

    yield return name;
  }
}

public static string[] ReadThings() => ReadThingsNames().ToArray();
```

Finally, you can ask for number of things:

```
private static string[] ReadThings() {
  string[] result = null;

  while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter number of things");

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int count) && 
        count >=0 && 
        count <= 1000) { //TODO: Put correct right border here
      result = new string[count];

      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Please, enter thing #{i + 1}");

    result[i] = Console.ReadLine();
  } 

  return result;
}
```

Then in order to read the things you can put

```
string[] things = ReadThings();
```